# Change email subject depending on body text

Tags: vba, email, outlook

We get email alerts from the system of one of our vendors with subjects "Alert for `[SITENAME]` - Uplink status changed" and where the email body will contain one of following two texts strings:

"the security appliance switched to using Internet 2 as its uplink."
or
"the security appliance switched to using Internet 1 as its uplink."

We need to read each email to see if an uplink has gone up or down and I want this to be visible from the subject.

```vb
Sub changesubject()
    
    Dim myMessage As Outlook.MailItem 
    Set myMessage = Outlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
    
    If myMessage.Body = "Internet 2 as its uplink" then
        myMessage.Subject = myMessage.Subject & "- PRIMARY LINK DOWN"
    End If
    
    If myMessage.Body = "Internet 1 as its uplink" then
        myMessage.Subject = myMessage.Subject & "- PRIMARY LINK UP"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If InStr(myMessage.Body, "Internet 2 as its uplink") then

Comment: Thanks for reply! I now have below code but it's still not working.

Sub changesubject()
    
    Dim myMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myMessage = Outlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    
    If InStr(myMessage.Body, "Internet 2 as its uplink") Then
        myMessage.Subject = myMessage.Subject & "- PRIMARY LINK DOWN"
    End If

    If InStr(myMessage.Body, "Internet 1 as its uplink") Then
        myMessage.Subject = myMessage.Subject & "- PRIMARY LINK UP"
    End If
    
End Sub

Comment: It is likely '.Save'. You can edit question with new information/code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Like` in your `If` statements instead of `=`. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) explains how the `Like` operator works. You can also Google "VBA Like" and you will get more results

```
Sub changesubject()

Dim myMessage As Outlook.MailItem 
Set myMessage = Outlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 

If myMessage.Body Like "*Internet 2 as its uplink*" then
    myMessage.Subject = myMessage.Subject & "- PRIMARY LINK DOWN"
End If

If myMessage.Body Like "*Internet 1 as its uplink*" then
    myMessage.Subject = myMessage.Subject & "- PRIMARY LINK UP"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but nothing is happening when I run this. I'm in the Outlook main window, I have selected the mail(s) that I want this to be run on. But the email subject just stays the same.

Comment: `Like` is case sensitive, if the body of the email doesn't have "Internet 2 as its uplink" or "Internet 1 as its uplink" exactly how you have it written then it won't catch it, you can change the `Like` to something shorter, for example `If myMessage.Body Like "*nternet 2*" Then`. But it just depends on what is written in the Body of the email, it worked perfectly fine for me when I used your given example @Tabell

Comment: @Tabell ActiveInspector.CurrentItem is an open item not a selection.